# fileChooser.showSaveDialog() is not working on mac

Tags: java, javafx, desktop-application

I am using below code for opening one dialog box for save the file from JavaFX application.

It is working fine on windows machine but same code is not working on mac system. When I click to open save dialog it appears for a while then it closes

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Game","*.xml"));

fileChooser.setTitle("Save game file");
File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(contextMenu.getScene().getWindow());
```

Please help me if I am doing any mistake here. Thanks a lot in advance...

Complete code for save dialog box

```
        exportXml.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

            fileChooser.setInitialFileName("exported.xml");

            fileChooser.setTitle("Save file");
            File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(button.getScene().getWindow());
            if (file != null) {

                FileChannel sourceChannel = null;
                FileChannel destChannel = null;
                try {
                    try {
                        sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(new File("source.xml")).getChannel();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e3) {
                        e3.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        destChannel = new FileOutputStream(file).getChannel();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        destChannel.transferFrom(sourceChannel, 0, sourceChannel.size());
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                   }finally{
                       try {
                        sourceChannel.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                       try {
                        destChannel.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
               }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You must use the javafx.stage.FileChooser class, not the awt or swing. Post a full MCVE, FileChooser works on Mac.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès , thanks for help. I am using javafx.stage.FileChooser; only. but not working.

Comment: Download an example from a tutorial "javafx filechooser example" and test. If it works then something is wrong in your code (we can't see, post an MCVE).

Comment: Hurrah!!! I got it, I was not using correct window to open save dialog box. Now I am using my BorderPane to open file chooser. Thanks @Jean-BaptisteYunès..